# If string1 or string2 in tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, string-matching

So I stumbled upon a problem (solved it eventually via experimentation) with checking for the existence of strings inside a tuple.

```
if 'String1' or 'String2' in tuple:
```

evaluated  `True` even if neither were in tuple.

```
if 'String1' in tuple or 'String2' in tuple:
```

gives me the desired result.

What did the first variant actually evaluate?

Edit:  @Cricket_007 ... the question you pointed to in your dupe report didn't cover the `in`, therefore I believe this not to be a dupe.

Comment: `if ('String1') or ('String2' in tuple):`

Comment: Go read the Python operator precedence table.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: Thanks @Barmar ... that kind of makes sense, not that I understand what `or`ing two stings does.

Comment: @Serjik Oring anything returns `True` if both are truthy, otherwise `False`. Non-empty strings are truthy, so `('String1' or 'String2')` is `True`. So what you write is `if True in tuple:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Consider using any as in `any(s in tuple for s in ('String1', 'String2'))`. Your issue is `'String1'` is 'truthy' as you have written it So `if True or 'String2' in tuple` will be `True` and is equivalent.

Comment: You were testing  `'String1'` or `'String2' in tuple`.  `if 'String1'` is always `True` if not `''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the `in` container checking,
If you break this statement: `if 'String1' or 'String2' in tuple:`

- `'String1'` returns True because testing `str()` returns `True` as long as the string is not empty
- `'String2' in tuple` returns True only if the string is **contained** in the tuple

The first condition always returns **True**.

The second line tests both variables for `in` containment first, and then performing `or` between the results

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Vinny, so because 'True' or (string2 in tuple) [which happens to be false] the whole thing is True?

Comment: @tink that's right. python breaks down the tests to `String1` OR `String2 in tuple`. The first always returns True